# Make build docker task more productive

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, microservices, docker-machine

I'm beginner with docker and I created a image with my application (with connections with oracle + db2 + gateways, in nodejs).

But I'm coding and for build it's take a longtime. Before I was using just node in my local machine, and I was running my project with nodemon. It was being very productive!

I need something like that, for to transform my build task faster.

Comment: You are re-building every time you change your code, or?

Comment: Yes, each change I rebuild, and that's very improductive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to rebuild your docker image every time, use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) instead.

For example run:

```
docker run -v /path/to/the/code/on/host:/path/to/the/code/on/container your image nodemon your_file.js
```